# How to call Woocommerce Class function from functions.php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

Woocommerce has a built in **class** (`WC_Structured_Data`) to genrate strucured data into product pages. This class or function is tied to `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action but it is missing from my temaplte file for some reason.

I am trying to call this function from my functions.php file without any luck.

**How could I call `generate_product_data()` function from my functions.php?** Here is the class: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/class-wc-structured-data.php